# Crafting AdSense-friendly URLs for special webpages

Tags: url, google-adsense

When many people make websites, they create simple friendly URLs with simple logic, however, my question involves more complex URLs.

Here's the story:

On my website, people can use an editor to make a photo collage using up to roughly 20 of 600,000 photos and/or they can add up to 20 text pieces. As progress is made, the URL changes to reflect the progress. At this moment, the URL ends in an encoded string representing the saved user data and so does the image.

I'll have zero problem if the collage is empty because then I don't need any encoded string to represent changes.

But the problem doesn't stop there.

Because I'm allowing up to 20 objects to be in the collage, the encoding length could be multiplied up to 20x. At this moment, I'm dividing each object by a slash.

My URL's then for example is as follows:

```
http://example.com/collage   <-- collage has nothing
http://example.com/collage/-0e43453536363242e   <-- collage has one object
http://example.com/collage/-0e43453536363242e/4363468340683068e   <-- collage has two objects

etc.
```

At this point one could suggest using words in the URL, but then I feel I'll be over the URL character limit in no time. For example:

For one object only in collage:

```
http://example.com/collage/box-100-in-from-left-10-in-from-top-with-width-200-pixels-and-height-300-pixels-of-greyscaled-sharpened-picture-1-from-gallery-bloke-on-december-25th-2014
```

For two objects in collage:

```
http://example.com/collage/box-100-in-from-left-10-in-from-top-with-width-200-pixels-and-height-300-pixels-of-greyscaled-sharpened-picture-1-from-gallery-bloke-on-december-25th-2014/text-saying-woooooo-in-red-letters-on-yellow-background-with-green-border-at-100-in-from-left-10-in-from-top-with-width-200-pixels-and-height-500-pixels
```

As you can see based on the friendly URLs alone for just a couple of objects (I haven't even hit 5 yet), the URLs are quite lengthy.

Is there a way to make my URLs even the slightest more friendlier than using codes in the URL to represent the pictures and/or text people added to their collage on my site and without breaking URL limits of any browser or device?

I'm also trying to make the AdSense robot less stupid as well since I'm running ads on the site.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could give your edits IDs and store them along with the connected change information in a database or textfile instead of storing the change information in the URL. You could even use some kind of friendly text as the ID.
2. If for any reason you need to store the changes within the URL it should likely be possible to improve and shorten the encoding, e.g. it might be possible to store the information not only of a single change but of all changes in a string like "4363468340683068e"

-> If you could do 1. or 2. you would have all the rest of the URL to contain friendly text.

If you want to stick to the text version of your above URL you could at least try to shorten them by removing possibly unnecessary words such as "from", "and" or "with".

Disclaimer: Actually the answers above seem quite obvious so I am not 100% sure, that I got the exact problem. Unfortunally I am not yet allowed to comment or question.

Comment: If I did #1, then I'd defeat my purpose. If I follow #2, then I'd probably confuse adsense even more. I'm trying to make each page adsense friendly. I want advertisers to understand the page.